# Is there as fast way to view the documentation for a symbol or class in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

option + click on a symbol like NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot reveals the Declaration, like this:

[image]

I can click "Open in Developer Documentation" from there, which opens Xcode's inferior "native" kind of documentation window. I then end up going to Google and typing in "NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot Apple" to get to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot.

It would be so cool if there was a quick way to have a preview popover just like the Declaration popover but for the documentation, briefly giving an overview of what this thing is. Does that exist, and if not, is there a plugin for Xcode that would do it?

Comment: fwiw, AppCode does a really good job of this

Comment: Is that an extension?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have been more clear. It's an IDE made by Jetbrains: https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

Comment: That's nice, but what if you really want to stick with Xcode for millions of other reasons?

Comment: oh yeah, don't get me wrong, I use XCode for maybe only three quarters of a million reasons, but because I use AppCode too, I've found it's really good at looking up documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the Quick Help inspector open on the right (Option-Command-3) at all times. Whatever is selected in the code, that is **reflected automatically** into the Quick Help inspector with an overview of the selected term. You don't have to do anything: the information is *always* being shown.

[image]

I should also add that what you find online at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot is in no way superior or inferior to the documentation included with Xcode; they are identical. That very same document is right there in Xcode. In this screen shot, you see Safari at the top and Xcode at the bottom; they are 100% the same thing.

[image]

---

<sub>Having said all that, I am not going to pretend that the relationship between code and documentation is good. It isn't. It's pretty terrible, a major series of downgrades from how it used to be back in early versions of Xcode. It used to be that you'd Option-click a term in the code and kaboom, you'd find yourself in the documentation for it. I don't know why they killed that great behavior. Still, these are the tools we've got, so it is well to learn to use them the best way they can be used.</sub>